# Is this not a proof of the Extreme Value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f : C \subset R^n \to R$ where $C$ is compact, then $\exists v \in C$ such that $f(v) = min_{x \in C} f(x)$

I basically thought that if $f$ is continuous, then it carries compact sets into compact sets. Therefore $f(C) = [a,b]$ and so this means it admits maximum and minimum $a = \min f$ and $b = \max f$. Does this alone (not directly maybe?) prove the existence of $v$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are basically correct (although the image set does not have to be a single closed interval if the domain is not connected).

Comment: Well I guess if the sets are not connected, I might be able to justify that it maps into a singleton, which is closed right?

Comment: It does not have to map to a singleton.  If the sets are not connected, then the image is just a union of (a finite number of) closed intervals, so the max is just the max of all the right endpoints.